# Why java substring doesn't crash?

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String s1 = "t";
System.out.println(s1.substring(1));
```

It's printing nothing but I wonder why it doesn't crash, it's definitely out of bounds exception or I'm missing something?

Comment: From the javadoc `"emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)`

Comment: @Anatoly did my answer help you? if so, could I please have a checkmark and upvote? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or
>   larger than the length of this String object.

here, your string is of length 1, your index is 1 and it is not negative => no exception thrown.

A little unintuitive? Yes. But substring() is a little unintuitive with its index choices in general :-)

Comment: What is silly about substrings? Everything is very clear about it and described in the docu. It might be different than what you expect - but if the docu describes it, its fine.

Comment: You're right, silly is wrong... "unintuitive" is correct. Changed.

Comment: Only if your intuition is wrong ;-) That convention, including the convention of the two-argument case (a half-open range), is simply the best convention for slicing sequences, and arguably for most other programming too. A better intuition for it is that the indices refer to gaps in between elements, akind to fenceposts: 0 is *before* the first element, 1 is between the first and second element, and so on.

Comment: It always depends on your expectation... It grinds my gears, when a programing language starts indexing arrays with "1" - Other people render this "intuitive" :P

Comment: I find it extremely intuitive.  Think of `str.substring(i)` as meaning "remove `i` characters from the beginning of `str`".  You can do that so long as the length of the string is `>=i`.  Otherwise, you get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

> Throws:
>   **IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if `beginIndex` is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Note the word *larger*. In your example, it isn't (it is *equal* to the length of the string).

Answer (score 1):

In the substring method there are 2 functions

1) substring(int 1, int 2)

in here int 1 = start position **counting from 0**

int 2 = end position **counting from 1**

ex:-

```
String test = "STACKOVERFLOW";
String result = test.substring(0,5); // result is equal to stack
```

2) substring(int 1)

in hear similar to above (1) the **starting point is int 1, (counting is started from 0)** and the end point = last position of the string

in your question

```
String s1 = "t";
System.out.println(s1.substring(1)); // "t" 's end point index is the end of the string

// "t" 's start point index is 1 which is also equal to the end of the string in this case
```

when you s1.substring(1) will equal to ""